# What function is the expectation of a function over a normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

Let $g(u,\delta)=E[f(x)]$ where the expectation is over $N(u,\delta^2)$.
Is there a characterization what function $g(u,\delta)$ can be produced this way? Is there a procedure solve the inverse problem, that is, given 
$g(u,\delta)$, the procedure should output $f(x)$?

This seems like a fundamental question. But I don't know any 
reference about it. Any reference will be appreciated.

Comment: The function $g $ is an integral.  See the wikipedia page on expected value under the general definition section.  The function has no closed form solution in general so you cannot invert it in that way.

Comment: This is an example of convolution with a gaussian.  (Specifically if you fix delta and consider g(u)).  There is a process know as deconvolution that I suggest you look in to.  I believe it is either possible or approximately possible.